# I want to pass the passed value of ejs back to my nodejs server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

[Here I am console.log() these values on app.js getting value from my page.ejs file, all the console.log() is working except req.body.name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXJZa.png)

[Here is the ss of page.ejs file. I am not able to get how to send back the value of <%= name %> back of my nodejs server. I have tried using the button and span tag but did not get the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRxbn.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to add value attribute in your button and change its name.

```
<button name="name" value="<%= name %>"><%= name %></button>
```